# Can't Remove Active Class From a Tab Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Well, I'm creating a Tab which the tab is the trigger to another element to add or remove class (I already commented in JS code). But, it seems that it doesn't work at all, and when I inspect it, it shows that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')` and the other element (iframe) is not showing up. I'm very noob in JavaScript, please help me to get through this. Anyway, here's the snippet :

```js
//Toggle the toggle and menu wrapper
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const menuTrigger = document.querySelector('.toggle'),
      menu = document.querySelector('.tabs');

menuTrigger.onclick = openMenu
  
function openMenu() {
      menuTrigger.classList.toggle('active');
      menu.classList.toggle('active');
}
  
})

//Add active class of tab on page load
var ready = (callback) => {
  if (document.readyState != "loading") callback();
  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
}
ready(() => {
  if(window.angular) return;
  document.querySelectorAll('.tab:first-child').forEach( first => {
    first.classList.add('active');
  })
  document.querySelectorAll('.content-item:first-child').forEach( first => {
    first.classList.add('active');
  })
})

//Add & remove class tab, contents, & menu on click
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
  let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
  let content = document.querySelectorAll('.content-item');
  let menuW = document.querySelector('tabs');
  let toggle = document.querySelector('toggle');
  
        for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {            
            tabs[i].addEventListener('click', () => tabClick(i));
        }

        function tabClick(currentTab) {
            removeActive();
            removeActiveTab();
            tabs[currentTab].classList.add('active');
            content[currentTab].classList.add('active');
            iframe = content[currentTab].querySelector('iframe');
            iframe.setAttribute('src', iframe.getAttribute('data-src'));
        }

        function removeActive() {
            for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                tabs[i].classList.remove('active');
                content[i].classList.remove('active');
                iframe = content[i].querySelector('iframe');
                iframe.removeAttribute('src');
            }
        }
        //Remove Menu Wrapper & Toggle Active Class on a Tabclick, which I confused
        function removeActiveTab() {
            menuW.classList.remove('active');
            toggle.classList.remove('active');
        }
})
```

```css
.container-tab {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 65px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: top;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    
        .wrapperleft {
            width: 10%;
            height: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    
        .wrapperright {
            width: 90%;
            height: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
         }

        .toggle {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
        }

        .toggle.active {
            background-color: blue;
            transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
            
        }

        .tabs {
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            width: 340px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 10%;
            animation-name: menu-out;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
        }
        
        @keyframes menu-out {
            0% {display: flex; opacity: 1;}
           99% {display: flex; opacity: 0;}
          100% {display: none; opacity: 0;}
        }

        .tabs.active{
            display: flex;
            animation-name: menu-in;
            animation-duration: 0.5s;
        }

        @keyframes menu-in {
            0% {display: none; opacity: 0;}
            1% {display: flex; opacity: 0.01;}
          100% {display: flex; opacity: 1;}
        }

        .tab {
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .tab.active {
            background-color: rgb(250, 97, 9);
        }

        .content {
            width: 100vw;
            margin-top: 50px;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .content-item {
            display: none;
            padding: 0px;
            border: none;
            animation-name: fade-out;
            animation-duration: 2.5s;
            position: absolute;
        }
        
        @keyframes fade-out {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
                display: block;
            }
            99% {
                opacity: 0;
                display: block;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
                display: none;
            }
        }

        .content-item.active {
            display: flex;
            border: none;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
            animation-name: fade-in;
            animation-duration: 3.5s;
        }

        @keyframes fade-in {
            0% {
                display: none;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            1% {
                display: block;
                opacity: 0.01;
            }
            100%{
                display: block;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        .content-iframe {
            border: none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 50vh;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container-tab">
      <div class="wrapperleft">
        <div class="toggle"></div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab">Tokyo</div>
            <div class="tab">Paris</div>
            <div class="tab">Washington</div>
            <div class="tab">Jakarta</div>
            <div class="tab">London</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapperright">

      </div>
</div>
  <div class="container-content">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-item">
              <div class="content-wrapper1">
                <div class="content-wrapper2">
                  <div class="content-wrapper3">
                    <iframe class= "content-iframe" data-src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe `let menuW = document.querySelector('tabs');` should be `let menuW = document.querySelector('.tabs');` . Note the `.` you are missing.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks for commenting, and let me try in my codepen

Comment: Oh my gosh my bad, this is really my fault, forgot the `.` . Thank you very much @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, it's really my fault which I forgot to add `.` in the front of `'tabs'` and `'toggle'`. And thanks to @CarstenLøvboAndersen who remind me to add the `.`